# Implementing a queue model in a relational database

Tags: sql, relational-database

The specification is simple: a queue is a set of elements in order. Each element of the queue has a precedent element; the first element of a queue has no precedent.

On any given day I would implement this with the following relations (tested on Postgres, should work on most other SQL enabled DBMSs):

```
CREATE TABLE queue
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR
)

CREATE TABLE element
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR
    id_precedent INT REFERENCES element(id),
    id_queue INT REFERENCES queue(id) NOT NULL
)
```

Now, one of the premises in the specification is not structurally guaranteed. Since the first element of the queue does not have a precedent, a `NOT NULL` constraint can not be applied to the `id_predecent` column. It is easy to see how data in the `element` table can quickly diverge from the model specified above.

In a DBMS with advanced features like Postgres, this aspect of the model can be guaranteed with a trigger. But this is a not so elegant solution, that may not apply in simpler DBMSs. Would there be a simpler way of implementing this particular model, fully enforcing its constraints, e.g. solely relying on standard SQL?

Comment: http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/

Comment: https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/what-is-select-skip-locked-for-in-postgresql-9-5/  and https://brandur.org/postgres-queues

Comment: This setup has a problem: How do I find the first element (a foreign key to `element` from `queue` would do). To avoid the NULL, you can link the last element to itself. I'd go with one of the existing implementations rather than re-invent the wheel. Implementing queues correctly in a relational database is a notoriously hard task.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe The query to find the first element of the queue with `id` number 100 is: `SELECT * FROM element WHERE id_queue = 100 AND id_precedent IS NULL;` Perfectly doable with this "setup".